# Getting to Mexico City Airport early in the morning

Tags: airport-transfer, mex, mexico-city

I was thinking of booking a flight that leaves at 6.15am in the morning from MEX, which means that I'll have to get there at 4.15am or so. What are my options for getting there so early in the morning, since I read that the metros run beginning at 5am?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify where you're starting from? And how much are you willing to spend on a trip?

Comment: I was looking for the easiest way to get to the airport from somewhere within Mexico City. I don't speak Spanish, so it also needs to be a reliable way, so I don't mind paying slightly more, for that convenience.

Comment: Get to a hotel at the airport and stay overnight would be easiest IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't told us where you are, I'll assume you're somewhere else within or near by Mexico City.  Your best bet will be a taxi.

Public transport (buses and trains) don't start until 4:30am or later:

> ### Metro (trains)
>
> Monday thru Friday from 5:00 to 24:00 hrs.
> Saturdays 6:00 to 24:00 hrs.
> Sundays and Holidays 7:00 to 24:00 hrs.
>
> ### Metrobus
>
> Monday thru Friday from 4:30 to 24:00 hrs.
> Saturdays and Sundays 5:00 to 24:00 hrs.
> [source; in Spanish](http://www.ciudadmexico.com.mx/transporte.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Can I call for a taxi that early in the morning? Approximately how much does it cost (say from the city center)?

Comment: @chinmayn: You can call for a taxi 24/7 in Mexico City. If you follow the link in my answer, it provides costs for taxis as well.